# force:refreshView not refreshing fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

I am using force:refreshView to refresh the page but the fields that have been selected in the page layout are not getting refreshed. I change a checkbox from unticked to ticked and then refresh the page using force:refreshView. I can see everything else refreshing apart from the fields that have been selected in the page layout. To see the checkbox ticked I have to use f5. Is there a way to refresh the values of the fields selected in the page layout?

Answer (score 1):

it might be related with some caching issues on the Salesforce side, I had the similar problem and to fix it I unfortunately had to use this to navigate to the same record.

```
navigateToRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    navEvt.fire();
},
```

It will redirect to the current record thus reloading the data.